# Where should I find new entries for translations?

Tags: smarty, prestashop

Inside a template I use this syntax:

```
{l s="some text" mod="module"}
```

The problem I have with this is that I can not find any entry of the "some text" inside any of the translation files inside module or anywhere else.

I believe I should run some kind of build but can not find any hints about that.

Answer (score 1):

Prestashop doesn't save your text, it is save the hash of your text. It meens that you need to use standart admin panel for your module translating. After that there will be created files with translations in the your module folder.

Regards

Comment: Thanks Alexander. The problem I am having with translations that I am able to edit them only in files directly as my vars limit is 1000. Isnt there any workaround ?

Comment: try to edit your .htaccess file with this code: php_value post_max_size "32M"
php_value max_input_vars 5000